# Pygame boundaries issue

Tags: python, pygame

So, I've been starting to learn PyGame from thenewboston on Youtube, and I'm kinda stuck on the [boundaries video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EHOYMe2HS8M&index=12&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq).

In the video, at 1:50, he types:

```
if lead_x > display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y > display_height or lead_y < 0:
        gameExit = True
```

This sets the boundaries of the game as the display. The game exits after the snake went past it. However, when I did the same thing, it seemed to have no effect on my program. The snake kept on going without ending the program. Is there anything that I did wrong? Source code is below. Thank you!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Snake')

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

pygame.display.update()

gameExit = False

lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300
lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = -10
                lead_x_change  = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change = 10
                lead_x_change = 0
    if lead_x > display_width or lead_x < 0 or lead_y > display_height or lead_y < 0:
        gameExit = True

    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: I copy & pasted your code, and it works like expected. I would use the `Rect` class instead of that inconvenient `if` statement, but maybe you want to follow your videos step by step.....

Answer (score 0):

Actually after testing your code with pygame, it seems to be working fine. However the character does go off screen. The code below will prevent the character from leaving the screen.

---

You need to check `lead_x` & `lead_y` added to amount moved (e.g. `lead_x` + `lead_x_changed`)
Altered line:

```
if (lead_x + lead_x_change) > display_width or (lead_x + lead_x_change) < 0 or (lead_y + lead_y_change) > display_height or (lead_y + lead_y_change) < 0:
```

Full example:

```
lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300
lead_x_change = 0
lead_y_change = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gameExit = False

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x_change = -10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x_change = 10
                lead_y_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                lead_y_change = -10
                lead_x_change  = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                lead_y_change = 10
                lead_x_change = 0


    lead_x += lead_x_change
    lead_y += lead_y_change
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [lead_x,lead_y,10,10])
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(15)
    if (lead_x + lead_x_change) > display_width or (lead_x + lead_x_change) < 0 or (lead_y + lead_y_change) > display_height or (lead_y + lead_y_change) < 0:
        gameExit = True

pygame.quit()
quit()
```